# Multiplication matrix per Vector

Tags: c, multithreading, matrix, parallel-processing, openmp

Any idea how  to parallel this function using OpenMP?

```
/*______ prod_matrix_vector __________ */

void dot(double matrix[], double vector[],int n, double result[]){
      
      for(int i=0,k=0;i<n*n,k<n;i=i+n,k++)
            for(int j=i,l=0;j<i+n,l<n;j++,l++)
                result[k]+=matrix[j]*vector[l];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The natural candidate for the parallelism is the outer loop, however, because it has two variable used to iterate (*i.e.,* `i` and `k`), we can not simply parallelized like it is using OpenMP.

Therefore, we first need to re-arrange the outer loop so that it contains only one variable. Let us choose the variable `k` since it is used to iterate over the array `result`. It is important to be the variable used to iterate over the array `result` because it is the only array being written into. Hence, it is the one that makes the more sense to distribute the iteration over that array among threads.

If one runs your double loop (with a n=4) and instead of `result[k]+=matrix[j]*vector[l];` prints the values of `i, k and j`, one gets the following:

```
i=0 k=0 j=0
i=0 k=0 j=1
i=0 k=0 j=2
i=0 k=0 j=3
i=4 k=1 j=4
i=4 k=1 j=5
i=4 k=1 j=6
i=4 k=1 j=7
i=8 k=2 j=8
i=8 k=2 j=9
i=8 k=2 j=10
i=8 k=2 j=11
i=12 k=3 j=12
i=12 k=3 j=13
i=12 k=3 j=14
i=12 k=3 j=15
```

So `i = k * n;`

So your double loop it is equivalent to :

```
  for(int k=0; k<n; k++){
    int i = k * n;
    for(int j=i, l=0; j <i+n, l<n; j++,l++)
         result[k]+=matrix[j]*vector[l];
  }
```

now the outer loop can parallelized with OpenMP, namely:

```
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for(int k=0; k<n; k++){
      for(int j= k * n, l=0; l<n; j++,l++)
         result[k] += matrix[j] * vector[l];
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer

Comment: I assume that this is a homework question. The real answer for production codes is "Use a BLAS library" (but that is probably not the one the question setter wants, even if it is the better answer!)

Comment: @JimCownie Yep, I could not agree more, one should not try to reinvent the wheel, specially a slower wheel ;)